# Spring Security return to login page AFTER a successful login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My Sring application have the following Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="org.webapp")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource restDataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(restDataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery())
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery());
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/image/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/spring/index").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/spring/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/spring/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/spring/index").permitAll();
    }

    private String getUserQuery() {
        return "SELECT login as username, senha as password "
                + "FROM usuario "
                + "WHERE login = ?";
    }

    private String getAuthoritiesQuery() {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT usuario.login as username, autorizacao.descricao as authority "
                + "FROM usuario, autorizacao_usuario, autorizacao "
                + "WHERE usuario.id = autorizacao_usuario.fk_usuario "
                + "AND autorizacao.id = autorizacao_usuario.fk_autorizacao "
                + "AND usuario.login = ? ";
    }

}
```

But I have one problem with that: After I inform the login credencials, the system return to login page instead the target page (/spring/home). I look in the stacktrack and no error is displayed.

Someone can see what's wrong?

**UPDATE**

CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        SavedRequest savedReq = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.ACCESS_DENIED_403);
        if (savedReq == null) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/spring/home");
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect(savedReq.getRedirectUrl());
        }
    }

}
```

CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler");
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/spring/erro-login");
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

the full source code of project can be seen here: https://github.com/klebermo/webapp1

Comment: Are you sure that authentication is succeeding ok? (have you walked through debug to check the user is actually authenticated). Would also need to see the code for your custom Success/Failure handlers to see what is going on regarding the redirecting

Comment: add them to the topic, but I think that's not the problem. In stacktrace, I can see the application is reaching them (in case, the failureHandler), but still it goes back to login page instead the home  or error page. And it's working perfectly when I have inMemory authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (or might be) the target error page is not listed as a "permit all" URL:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler");
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/spring/erro-login");
}
```

On authentication failure you are redirecting to `"/spring/erro-login"` - however, this is not listed in your security ant matcher, so this URL gets caught by:

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

As it is not authenticated, you cannot access that URL so Spring redirects you to the login page.

Try updating to:

```
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/spring/erro-login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/image/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Comment: Yes, it was exactly that. Kind of a silly mistake mine, actually. Now, I need figure out why the login is failling, because the credencials which I am entering are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you missed to add `.defaultSuccessUrl("/spring/home")` in your `formLogin` config.

Also If I were you would always add `.failureUrl("/login?login_error=1")` just to be sure about being logged in or failure occurred while logging in.

Comment: both situations are handled by the methods successHandler and failureHandler and its respective class. And the application is reaching them when I run it, according to stacktrace messages.